# What do I measure a different voltage over the 100k ohm resistor and the output voltage in the circuit included in the body?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Hey so I am building a simple IR emitter detector based security system as a beginner project. The detector is a photodiode acting as a current source. I am not sure what the value of this current is so I chose something random for the schematic as its not important to the question.

When I measure the potential difference between the output terminal of the op amp and ground I get V = -7.22 V. When I measure the potential difference between one terminal of the resistor and ground, I get a similar value. When I measure the potential difference over the 100k ohm resistor, I get roughly 15 volts though. Where does this discreprency come from? If the inverting terminal is grounded then the voltage over the resistor should be equal to the output terminal voltage correct? I am using a series connected DC power supply set as my ground if that helps at all.[image]

Comment: Where is your ground for the current source? What are the opposite ends of batteries connected to? Is this an actual circuit you built, or is it just the schematic with a simulation?

Comment: You may want to use the built-in circuit simulator and schematic editor - just Edit the question, and click on the schematic symbol in the little menu bar on top of the editor pane. This is a full version of CircuitLab, and you may get help quicker by having a functional simulation available here so that answers can just reuse it and tweak it appropriately.